# updating a variable jquery on event change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a interactive experience using jQuery. I am trying to make it so my character can go into multiple rooms.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 39:
            $("#barry").attr("src", "img/characters/BarryBallRight.png")
            $("#barry").stop().animate({
                left: 1021
            }, 1250, function() {
                position = $(this).position();
                getCurrentPos(position);
                if (barryPosX > $("#canvas").width()) {
                    if (state == 0) {
                        state = 1
                        changeBackground(state);
                        // reset barry
                        $(this).css({
                            'left': '-100px'
                        });
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            left: '+=150px'
                        })

                    };
                    if (state == 1) {
                        state = 2;
                        changeBackground(state);
                        // reset barry
                        $(this).css({
                            'left': '-100px'
                        });
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            left: '+=150px'
                        })
                    };
                };
            })
```

My problem as you can see is that the last state that runs overwrites the previous one, meaning that the `changeBacktround()` function will change the background of the most recent `state` that is set i.e `2`

I know there is some logic I am missing.

Note that the `getCurrentPos()` function just retrieves the current `$("#barry")` position on screen. The `changeBackground()` function is switch statement that takes the current state and changes the screen background accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (state == 0) {
   state = 1
   changeBackground(state);
   // reset barry
   $(this).css({
   'left': '-100px'
   });
  $(this).stop().animate({
  left: '+=150px'
    })

   } else if (state == 1) {
      state = 2;
      changeBackground(state);
      // reset barry
      $(this).css({
       'left': '-100px'
      });
      $(this).stop().animate({
       left: '+=150px'
        })
      };
```

As far as I understand you need to use else if. Right now hes always going into the 2nd condition if the state starts with 0. With else if its going either into the condition 'state == 0' or into 'state == 1' condition but not into both

Comment: I cant believe i missed this... its been i long day.

Comment: I liked your explanation as well!